# Unsubscribe from Firestore stream - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs

Recently I implemented Firebase into my Angular project and I have a question about unsubscribing from data stream.

When you use classic HTTP calls, observables from this are finite, but with the firestore, these are infinite, so you have to unsubscribe. But when I do so (after destroying component and log out), I still get an error in console and I can see that requests are still sending (or persisting).

In the network tab I can see this in the request timing:

> Caution: request is not finished yet

This error pops up after I log out (Its probably caused because of my rules that I set)

> FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions

And also, I still get an error even if I use `async` pipe in angular.

Here is my current solution:

**data.service.ts**

```
  items: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(db: AngularFirestore) {
    this.items = db.collection("data").valueChanges();
  }

  getItems() {
    return this.items;
  }
```

**home.component.ts**

```
  req: Subscription;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.req = this.dataService.getItems().subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res);
      },
      err => console.log(err),
      () => console.log("completed")
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    console.log("ya");
    this.req.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Thanks for your advices!

Answer (score 2):

**home.component.ts**

```
import { takeWhile } from "rxjs/operators";

@Component({...})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  isAlive: boolean = true;

  ...

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataService.getItems()
      .pipe(takeWhile(() => this.isAlive))
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.isAlive = false;
  }

}
```

`takeWhile` is what u needed

Comment: It did not help, after logging off and setting the value to false the connection still persists. :/

Comment: When I log out, it takes about 2 - 3 minutes to terminate this connection. I dont know if this is right way or not...

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the rxjs operators, eg take (1) after taking the value, it unsubscribe by itself

```
this.dataService.getItems().pipe(take(1)).subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res);
      },
      err => console.log(err),
      () => console.log("completed")
    );
```

Comment: And what If I want persist connection, but only when user is logged in?